# .map Function React Hook useEffect not re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api, array.prototype.map

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        
        description:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        img:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        categories:{
            type: Array
        },

        size:{
            type: String
        },
        
        color:{
            type: String
        },

        price:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        inStock:{
            type: Boolean, default: true
        }

    },
    {timeStamps: true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)
```

I have a problem in mapping product properties like color and size.

Product data is received from the backend using Axios but the `useEffect` is not re-rendering and the product objects like color and size are not present at the first load of the component. They are undefined because of which `.map` is not a function error is showing

```js
 const location = useLocation()
 const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2]
 const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
 
 useEffect(() =>{
        console.log("useEffect")
        const getProduct = async ()=>{
            try{
              const res = await publicReq.get("/products/find/" + id)
              console.log(res.data)
              setProduct(res.data)
              console.log("useEffect worked")
              console.log(product)
              console.log(product.color)
              console.log(product.size)
              console.log(product.title)
            }catch (err){
                console.log(err)
                console.log("not running")
            }
          }
          getProduct()
    }, [id])
    
    <Filter>
    <FilterTitle>{console.log("running")}Color</FilterTitle>
    {product.color?.map((c) =>{
     console.log("lo running")
     return(
         <Color color={c} key={c} onClick={() => setCol(c)}/>
               )               
               })}
           </Filter>
```

Comment: Try converting response to ```json``` with ```const jsonRes = res.json()``` and then ```setProduct(jsonRes.data)``` because the error message shows ```unexpected token '<'``` which means the response type was expected to be ```json``` but it's getting as ```raw html```.

Comment: so you have only 1 useEffect in the parent component so when you switch pages you get different id for each child? not sure if it works but add this instead [id, [ ] ] in the useEffect

Comment: What is `product.color`? Are you sure it's an array?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to do this: `const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2]`. If you're using react-router for instance, the `id` does not have to be awkwardly extracted from location.pathname

Comment: @YashSharma I tried it shows an error res.json() is not a function it works with fetch only I think

Comment: @c0dm1tu [id, []] causes infinite loop

Comment: @ChrisG no product.color is not an array in the userSchema color:{
            type: String
        },

Answer (score 1):

`.map` only works on arrays. Check if your `product.color` data is in the form of an array. An easy way to check is by doing `console.log(Array.isArray(products.color))` In addition, it wouldn't hurt to initialize your product state as the form of the data you're receiving , so no type errors or bugs occur on a component's mount. Below is an example.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({size: "", title: "",color: []})
```

```js
function isArray(arr){
  return Array.isArray(arr)
}

console.log(isArray([]))
console.log(isArray([1,2,3]))
console.log(isArray("no"))
console.log(isArray("[]"))
```

Comment: I am using mongodb in userSchema product.color is not an array but there should be multiple colors of a product Do I need to initialize it as an array in the backend(userSchema) You mean product.color should be in array form in backend  ??

Comment: I added userSchema code above

Comment: In your product schema, color is a String. You can't use .map on a string. It must be an array.

Comment: Solved Thank you so much bro You are right the product.color is not in a Array type in the mongodb Schema as you see above I converted it to type: Array and now product.color.map is running Thank you so much

Comment: To display the color string though, you don't need to use .map() at all. You can simply do product.color

Answer (score 0):

(Solved) The error is I didn't initialize the product.color in Array type instead and the .map() function works only on Arrays.

color:{
type: Array
},

this should be the code of color in mongoDB Schema